# installing Grid Engine "cannot reach qmaster"

Tags: cluster, portable-batch-system, gridengine

I want to install Grid Engine on my laptop.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 under VirtualBox 4.1.6.

(The purpose of installing Grid Engine is not to compute anything, I just want a working Grid Engine environment to be able try out bash scripting for array jobs etc. The jobs which I would run would just do "sleep", so the cluster would consist of only one single node. My laptop has a dualcore CPU but I don't know if that's relevant here.)

I am following the instructions from http://astoryworthtelling.wordpress.com/2009/08/25/installing-sge-on-ubuntu-single-machine-local-install/ and have tried to install Grid Engine like this:

```
sudo apt-get install gridengine-master gridengine-exec gridengine-client gridengine-qmon gridengine-common
```

Then I start qmon with sudo. The GUI starts alright, I click on "Queue Control". What then happens is that a window pops up saying "cannot reach qmaster":

[image]

If I click "Retry" I get another popup which is slightly more informative, "Unable to contact qmaster using port 6444 on host "anton-VirtualBox":

[image]

My question is, how can I fix this? Help to get Grid Engine running and fixing this would be very much appreciated, thank you.

P.S.: One more thing, maybe it helps to help track down the error. When I try to use qstat from within bash, I get this message:

```
anton@anton-VirtualBox:~$ qstat
error: commlib error: access denied (client IP resolved to host name "localhost". This is not identical to clients host name "anton-VirtualBox")
error: unable to contact qmaster using port 6444 on host "anton-VirtualBox"
```

P.P.S.: I have some experience using Grid Engine, but absolutely zero installing or administering it.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially it's complaining that a reverse lookup of your IP returns `localhost` instead of `anton-Virtualbox` and your queue is setup to use `anton-Virtualbox` as the qmaster.  So you need to update your hosts file.

Mine reads:

```
my.full.local.ip        my.fully.qualified.hostname    shorthostname
127.0.1.1               my.fully.qualified.hostname    shorthostname
127.0.0.1               localhost
...
```